# How to align text to top or bottom in css

Tags: html, css

This is my code i try to align texts `name` and `age` to bottom but it does not work

```
<div class="tiles">
    <div id="metro-array">
        <a class="metro-tile" style="cursor: pointer; width: 110px; height: 110px;  display: block; background-color: deepSkyBlue;  color: #fff;">
            <span style="margin-top:100px"> 
                Name 
            <span>
            Age
         </a>
         <a class="metro-tile" style="cursor: pointer; width: 110px; height: 110px; display: block; background-color: deepSkyBlue;  color: #fff;">
             name2
             Age 2
         </a>         
    </div>
  </div>
```

My Css

```
.tiles {
    font-family:'Lato', Helvetica, sans-serif;
    line-height: 28px;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #333;
    font-weight: lighter;
 }   
 #metro-array a,  #downloads a {
    font-weight: normal;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    float:left;
 }

}
```

I tried these for that span

```
margin-top:100px and `margin-top:-100px`
```

but it is not working

Comment: `span` is inline element. First make it `block` or `inline-block` and then add `margin`.

Comment: And also you"re not closing `span` after _Name_

Comment: Thanks man , it sounds good , answer it i will upvote you @Jashwant

Comment: @Thamaraiselvam, added comment as answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have edited your code to accomplish the margin you are aiming for.

http://plnkr.co/edit/VJYpZa76UL06FLlRpRJr?p=preview

I moved all the styles to `style.css` because it is good practice to [separate your CSS from your HTML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns).

Answer (score 0):

please remove float and display blog and try it.

**[Love Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MansukhKhandhar/c99pozrb/2/)**

HTML

```
<div class="tiles">
<div id="metro-array">
    <a class="metro-tile align-top">
        <span> 
            Name 
        <span>
        Age
     </a>
     <a class="metro-tile align-middle">
         name2
         Age 2
     </a>  
            <a class="metro-tile align-bottom">
         name3
         Age 3
     </a>  
</div>
```

CSS

```
    .tiles {
    font-family:'Lato', Helvetica, sans-serif;
    line-height: 28px;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #333;
    font-weight: lighter;
 }   
 #metro-array a,  #downloads a {
    font-weight: normal;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 110px;
    height: 130px;
    display: table-cell;
    background-color: deepSkyBlue;
    color: #fff;

 }
a.align-bottom{
    vertical-align:bottom;
}
a.align-top{
    vertical-align:top;
}
a.align-middle{
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can apply the display block style to the element and it should fix the top and bottom margin issue. Before that make correction on your code. close the span tag.

```
<span style="display:block;margin-top:100px;">Name</span>
```

If you need it stick to left side or right side of any other inline element, use the float:left or float:right style.

Answer (score 0):

`span` is an inline element. First make it `block` or `inline-block` and then add `margin`.